# How to view code difference by changeset in TFS through a web-based interface?

Tags: tfs

Is there a way to look at code differential between previous and current versions of a changeset in TFS 2005/08 through a web-based interface?

I am aware of `Changeset.aspx` with a `artifactMoniker` parameter that retrieves the changeset and related files. But I would also like to view the code delta in a web based manner.

Answer (score 4):

This can be achieved in TFS 2008 via the Visual Studio Team System Web Access.

First you need to open an individual Changeset details. This can be done for example by looking at a build (the Builds tab), and selecting one of the changesets associated with the build.
For some reason the version of Web Access I currently have at hand had a bug in that the link into a Changeset webpage is missing the changeset number. A quick manual fix of the URL helped.

This is the URL that is linked to

```
http://tfsappserver:8090/UI/Pages/Scc/ViewChangeset.aspx?changeseturi=vstfs:///VersionControl/Changeset/8695
```

Notice I needed to add the **changeset** parameter manually.

```
http://tfsappserver:8090/UI/Pages/Scc/ViewChangeset.aspx?changeseturi=vstfs:///VersionControl/Changeset/8695&changeset=8695
```

The page lists all the code files that has changed and for each file you can compare it with another version. The comparison option is available from *dropdown menu* on the file.

Here is what it looks like:
[image: VSTS ViewChangeset]